# How to resolve HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found error in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

When i Submitted my contact form in my website its Displaying Error like  **HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.**

Please help me how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Please google the error messages before you post a question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with IIS settings. The below link should help you -

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/571514/The-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served

Answer (score 0):

All the status codes have a very crisp meaning in IIS. You can view the status codes here and their meaning.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891

In your case, most likely the extension of the page you are posting to would be blocked. You can get more information about precisely what went wrong by doing a Failed Request tracing in IIS.

http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis